# Why doesn't this timed while loop work (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I am semi-advanced and don't understand why this code does not execute properly. I want the code to execute something at a certain time. Thanks for your input. /Hank

```
running=1;

while running==1

    if hour(now)==17 & minute(now)==4 & second(now)==59
        (Do Stuff)
        running=0;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because `second` returns a double array, and with floating point double precision, the condition `second(now)==59` may never be true. I would replace it with something like: `abs(second(now)-59)<1e-3` or whatever threshold you think is appropriate. The values returned by `hour` and `minute` are integer, so the equality test should be valid.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [`second`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/finance/second.html) does not return an integer. Therefore the equality second(now) == 59 is ambigious.

It is better to use `round(second(now))==59`